# How can I make this equation fit in 1 line

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I want to fit this equation in 1 line but the too wide error keeps popping up. What should i do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$-\dfrac{\ln
\left(\frac{
\left|2
\left(\cos
\left(c\right)+\cos
\left(b\right)-2\cos
\left(a\right)\right)\sqrt{-\cos^2
\left(x\right)+
\left(\cos
\left(c\right)+\cos
\left(b\right)\right)\cos
\left(x\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\cos
\left(c\right)}+2\sqrt{
\left(\cos
\left(a\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\right)\cos
\left(c\right)+\cos
\left(a\right)\cos
\left(b\right)-\cos^2
\left(a\right)}
\left(2\cos
\left(x\right)-\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\right)-2
\left(\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\right)\cos
\left(x\right)+
\left(-\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)+2\cos
\left(a\right)\right)
\left|\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\right|+\cos^2
\left(c\right)-\cos^2
\left(b\right)\right|}{
\left|2\cos
\left(x\right)-\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\right|}\right)-\ln
\left(\frac{
\left|2
\left(\cos
\left(c\right)+\cos
\left(b\right)-2\cos
\left(a\right)\right)\sqrt{-\cos^2
\left(x\right)+
\left(\cos
\left(c\right)+\cos
\left(b\right)\right)\cos
\left(x\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\cos
\left(c\right)}-2\sqrt{
\left(\cos
\left(a\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\right)\cos
\left(c\right)+\cos
\left(a\right)\cos
\left(b\right)-\cos^2
\left(a\right)}
\left(2\cos
\left(x\right)-\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\right)-2
\left(\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\right)\cos
\left(x\right)+
\left(-\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)+2\cos
\left(a\right)\right)
\left|\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\right|+\cos^2
\left(c\right)-\cos^2
\left(b\right)\right|}{
\left|2\cos
\left(x\right)-\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(b\right)\right|}\right)}{\sqrt{
\left(\cos
\left(b\right)-\cos
\left(a\right)\right)\cos
\left(c\right)-\cos
\left(a\right)\cos
\left(b\right)+\cos^2
\left(a\right)}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This equation does not fit in 1 line. How can i make it fit in 1 line and still be able to see it properly

Comment: you have not provided a usable example. in particular whether it fits depends how wide your line is, but you have provided no information. But whatever the equation there are always three choices. write it over several lines or write it in a smaller font or define some local varuables so that the expression is not so big. Note your tex markup is far more complicated than it needs to be remove most of the left right eg `\cos\left(b\right)` should be`\cos(b)` the `\left\right` there just add unwanted space and make the expression even wider than it should be

Comment: The text width is the usual width in the document class article

Comment: Throwing in a `\usepackage{amsmath}` so that it compiles, Overleaf says that your line is 1386pt too wide.  I believe that's about 20 inches.  How would you fit that in one line if you were using a pencil and paper?  (Also, this doesn't really have anything to do with Overleaf.)

Comment: I fixed your example this time so people can run it to see the issue.  But do you _really_ want to express this, how are your readers supposed to read it, even if you make it fit? It would be far better to define variables for some sub terms that make sense, so it ends up being `$\ln(a/b+c)$` or some such with a b and c defined earlier

Comment: Then how do i write the equation so that it is viewable? Also what sub terms can i define to make it in the form $\ln (a/ b+c)$

Comment: Changing `\cos a` to `A` etc, it's down to 558pt too wide.  The textwidth of the above example is 345pt, so I've gotten it down to 260% of the available width.  You need to ask yourself: "what is the reader supposed to get from reading this expression?"  At the moment, you're trying to cram way too much information into way too little space, and no one will be able to make sense of the result.

Comment: It is really your job as author to decide which are the subterms that are meaningful to name as variables and what names to give them. However @Mico has done an excellent attempt in the answer posted.

Comment: The formula, as it stands, is a tad more than 61 centimeters wide. Unless you have *very* wide paper, it won't fit.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for helping me in this problem.

Answer (score 17):

Using the `\resizebox` macro to squeeze your equation into the width of the textblock will lead to something like this:

[image]

Now I may be wrong here, but I suspect your readers will *not* be overjoyed when told to behold this sight. Instead, I think they would very much appreciate if you broke up the equation into its main components and then displayed these components across several lines. Say,

[image]

You're obviously free to choose other variable names than `A`, `B`, `C`, `u_1`, `u_2`, `u_3`, `u_4`, and `u_5`.

Observe that I've tried to greatly cut down on the visual clutter by not placing parentheses around the arguments of `\cos` and `\cos^2`. Observe also that not a single `\left` or `\right` sizing directive remains in the following code. Yupp, all 89 `\left` and all 89 `\right` directives are gone -- and they won't be missed.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' and '\shortintertext' macros
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert

\begin{document}
\noindent
The solution is of the form $-(A-B)/C$, where
\begin{align*}
A &= \ln(\abs{u_1+u_2-u_3+u_4}/\abs{u_5}) \\
B &= \ln(\abs{u_1-u_2-u_3+u_4}/\abs{u_5}) \\
C &= \sqrt{(\cos b-\cos a)\cos c-\cos a\cos b+\cos^2 a}\\
\shortintertext{and}
u_1 &= 2(\cos c+\cos b-2\cos a)\sqrt{-\cos^2 x+(\cos c+\cos b)\cos x-\cos b\cos c}\\
u_2 &= 2\sqrt{(\cos a-\cos b)\cos c+\cos a\cos b-\cos^2 a}\,(2\cos x-\cos c-\cos b)\\
u_3 &= 2(\cos c-\cos b)\cos x+(-\cos c-\cos b+2\cos a)\,\abs{\cos c-\cos b}\\
u_4 &= \cos^2 c-\cos^2 b\\
u_5 &= 2\cos x-\cos c-\cos b
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```